# Understanding part of a proof for Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, proof-explanation

I'm trying to wrap my head around this proof I'm reading for the discrete case of the Chebyshev inequality:

$$P(|X-EX|<\epsilon)\ge 1-\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$$

Proof:

Without loss of generality we assume that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ for which the first $k$ values of the random variable $|X-EX|$ are less than that $\epsilon$, and the rest are not less than that $\epsilon$. Then

$$P(|X-EX|<\epsilon)=1-\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i,$$

where $p_i=P(X=x_i)$. To find $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i$ lets look at the variance of the random variable $|X-EX|$(I think there might be a mistake here since in the next line we are looking at $Var(X)$):

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i(x_i-EX)^2+\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i(x_i-EX)^2 \ge \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i(x_i-EX)^2,$$

from where

$$\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \ge \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}.$$

Finaly we get, that

$$P(|X-EX| < \epsilon) \ge 1-\frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}$$

I don't get that last part, i.e. why $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \ge \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$?

Comment: Because for $i\ge k+1$ you have $(x_i - EX)^2\ge \epsilon^2$.

Comment: From $Var(X)\ge \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i(x_i-EX)^2$ you obtain $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \le \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ not "$\ge$" by dividing  the inequality by $(x_i - EX)^2\ge \epsilon^2$. By replacing $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i$ through larger value  $ \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ you obtain the final inequality.

Comment: Clearly a case where the general proof, not assuming that $X$ is discrete, is less clumsy and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every value of $(x_i-EX)^2$ is greater than $\epsilon^2$ we have

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)\ge \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i(x_i-EX)^2 \ge \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i\epsilon^2.$$

From there by dividing by $\epsilon^2$ we get $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \le \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ and not the other way around.

From $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \le \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ it follows that $1- \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty p_i \ge 1-\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ and from there we get

$P(|X-EX|<\epsilon) \ge 1-\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$.